# How can i disable user interaction with my textbox in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently use a text box in wich i redirect the output wich normally happens in the python shell window. I want to disable the user being able to interact with it besides using the scrollbar.

```
textbox = ScrolledText(master, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set, state = "disabled")
```

state = "disabled" also deactivates the interaction between my programm and the textbox

My current code for the text box:

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.grid(row = 9, column = 0)

textbox = ScrolledText(master, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
textbox.grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = N, pady = 20)
scrollbar.config(command = textbox.yview)

def redirector(inputStr):
    textbox.insert(INSERT, inputStr)

sys.stdout.write = redirector
```

Comment: when you have to add text then enable `state`, add text, and disable `state`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to add text then set state `normal`, insert text, and `disable` it again

```
text['state'] = 'normal'
text.insert('end', 'Hello World\n')
text['state'] = 'disabled'
```

---

Minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as st
import datetime

# --- functions ---

def on_click():
    text['state'] = 'normal'
    text.insert('end', str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '\n')
    text['state'] = 'disabled'

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

text = st.ScrolledText(root, state='disabled')
text.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='ADD', command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```